# WARN TransportChannelHandler: Exception in connection from /172.31.88.129:20624 java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Too large frame: 51356034472965202

Tags: apache-spark, kubernetes

I asked this question before, and the answer is that the k8s version is incompatible with the spark version, which causes the following problem
[problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oDRUa.png)

```html
 WARN TransportChannelHandler: Exception in connection from /172.31.88.129:20624
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Too large frame: 5135603447296520289
        at org.sparkproject.guava.base.Preconditions.checkArgument(Preconditions.java:119)
        at org.apache.spark.network.util.TransportFrameDecoder.decodeNext(TransportFrameDecoder.java:148)
        at org.apache.spark.network.util.TransportFrameDecoder.channelRead(TransportFrameDecoder.java:98)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:379)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:365)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:357)
        at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline$HeadContext.channelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:1410)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:379)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:365)
        at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.fireChannelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:919)
        at io.netty.channel.nio.AbstractNioByteChannel$NioByteUnsafe.read(AbstractNioByteChannel.java:166)
        at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKey(NioEventLoop.java:722)
        at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeysOptimized(NioEventLoop.java:658)
        at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeys(NioEventLoop.java:584)
        at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:496)
        at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$4.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:986)
        at io.netty.util.internal.ThreadExecutorMap$2.run(ThreadExecutorMap.java:74)
        at io.netty.util.concurrent.FastThreadLocalRunnable.run(FastThreadLocalRunnable.java:30)
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833)
23/05/13 03:11:44 INFO Master: 172.31.88.129:20624 got disassociated, removing it.
```

The answer I checked before is that k8s is incompatible with the version of spark. However, my current version of k8s is 1.23.15 and spark is 3.2.2. Then, I found that spark3.2.2 is compatible with k8s version >1.20 in the spark official document
[Version compatibility described on the official website](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZUZci.png)So now I have no idea what I'm supposed to do.

By the way, I connected spark using big data tool, my sparkUI and master nodes were exposed through NodePort, sparkUI was able to connect properly, but the client was unable to connect

[UI](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wb9no.png)

[big data tool](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0czb1.png)

[svc](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HMGA3.png)

[k8s version](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JAxOR.png)

and i found out that spark can not connected with Kubernetes API Server because [Error during 'GET: /api/v1/version'](https://i.stack.imgur.com/orGju.png).Still seems to be a version problem?